# Почему ++$x работает быстрее, чем $x++?

Tags: perl

Итак, давайте выполним 2 скрипта, и убедимся, что `++$x` работает быстрее...

**Скрипт-1:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $x = 0;

foreach (1..5_000_000)
{
 $x++; 
}
```

---

```
perl -d:NYTProf test.pl
```

---

```
nytprofhtml --open
```

---

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Скрипт-2:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $x = 0;

foreach (1..5_000_000)
{
 ++$x;
}
```

---

```
perl -d:NYTProf test.pl
```

---

```
nytprofhtml --open
```

---

Результат: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вопрос: **Почему `++$x` работает быстрее, чем `$x++`?**

Comment: Я хочу знать как Вы это обнаружили.

Comment: @Other, обновил. И это обнаружил не я...

Comment: Я сейчас *на Java* попробовал измерить время выполнения кодов `x++` и `++x` соответственно и абсолютно каждый раз время выполнения разное. Так что попробуйте-ка ещё немного раз сделать измерения. **Хоть раз**, по моему мнению, **результат будет иной**, то есть в пользу `x++`.

Comment: @nick На perl 5.12.4 приведенный в вопросе пример действительно дает совершенно разное время выполнения, не говорящее вообще ни о чем. в среднем время выполнения равно. При этом на моем Core i7 такой цикл на 25 млн итераций проходит за 1.3 sec, пустой цикл (без x++) за 0.9 sec. т.е. судить о времени операции на таком примере не корректно. Однако, я сделал другой тест https://pastebin.com/HNdjcsM5  если операции внутри `x++` - то время в среднем не отличается. Но вот если как в листинге то `y=x++` в среднем 4.5 sec, `y=++x` в среднем 3.6 sec. Разница на лицо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`++$x` работает грубо говоря в два шага:

1. делаем `$x + 1`;
2. передаем значение.

`$x++` (присваиваемый) работает сложнее, его обычно нельзя реализовать без промежуточной копии:

1. сохраняем значение `$x` в `$temp`;
2. делаем `$x + 1`;
3. передаем значение `$temp`.

P.S.: Не присваиваемый `$x++`, в умных компиляторах/интерпретаторах, может не отличается от `++$x`.

P.P.S.: При сильных оптимизациях еще все зависит от прилегающих операций, и при использовании простых типов разница скорее всего вообще пропадет.

Comment: а в пхп тоже такая же телега?

Comment: Везде присваиваемый `X++` требует дополнительных операций процессора.

Comment: @Максим, вообще везде? Даже в C++ и в Java?

Comment: Думаю, что совсем умный _компилятор_ при генерации кода просто переставит присвоение и инкремент местами.

Comment: @Mike, это общее описание отличий `пост-` от `пре-`. В зависимости от прилегающих операций, простыня ASM команд может существенно отличаться.

Comment: @nick, дописал ответ.

Comment: Только что проверял пример ТС на perl 5.12.4  не удалось добиться никакой значимой разницы на операции инкремента без присвоения. Так что оптимизатор в perl похоже справляется. С присвоением есть очевидная разница `y=x++` 4.5 sec против `y=++x` 3.6 sec, на таком https://pastebin.com/HNdjcsM5 примере. Результаты: https://pastebin.com/g2CSfdtN

Comment: @Mike, с большой вероятностью сработает только последнее присваивание. Сработает 80 инкрементов и одно присваивание за итерацию в цикле. Возможно разница во времени станет еще больше, если в цикле будет не 80 операций а одна.

Comment: @Максим Нет, у perl нет такой оптимизации. с одной операцией https://pastebin.com/kQh2yA1r (количество циклов то же)